# SQL Break down path column into hierarchical data

Tags: sql, sql-server

The existing table looks like this:

```
Categories
----------------------------------------------
Drinks\Soda
Drinks\Juice\Fruit Juice\Apple Juice\Sugar Free
Food\Fruit\Oranges
Food\Fruit\Apples\Golden
Food\Fruit\Apples\Red Delicious
Food\Vegetables\Potatoes
Food\Meat
Food
```

And I need to process it into a hierarchical data table, like this:

```
Id  | ParentId |  Category   | Full path
------------------------------------------
1   | null     | Drinks      | Drinks
2   | 1        | Soda        | Drinks\Soda
3   | 1        | Juice       | Drinks\Juice
4   | 3        | Fruit Juice | Drinks\Juice\Fruit Juice
5   | 4        | Apple Juice | Drinks\Juice\Fruit Juice\Apple Juice
6   | 5        | Sugar Free  | Drinks\Juice\Fruit Juice\Apple Juice\Sugar Free
7   | null     | Food        | Food
8   | 7        | Fruit       | Food\Fruit
9   | 8        | Oranges     | Food\Fruit\Oranges
10  | 8        | Apple       | Food\Fruit\Apples
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I thought I had it with a cross apply, but then I get multiple rows for each parent, I end up with something like the table below which is not what I need:

```
Category   | Full path
------------------------------------------
Drinks      | Drinks\Soda
Soda        | Drinks\Soda
Drinks      | Drinks\Juice
Juice       | Drinks\Juice
```

---

Edit: This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[food_categories3](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [category] [varchar](350) NULL)

insert into food_categories3
values 
(1,'Drinks\Soda'),
(2,'Drinks\Juice\Fruit Juice\Apple Juice\Sugar Free'),
(3,'Food\Fruit\Oranges'),
(4,'Food\Fruit\Apples\Golden'),
(5,'Food\Fruit\Apples\Red Delicious'),
(6,'Food\Vegetables\Potatoes'),
(7, 'Food\Meat'),
(8,'Food')

select * from food_categories3

 SELECT distinct X.category,
     splitted.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS cat  
 FROM  (SELECT  category,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(category, '\', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS cat  
     FROM  food_categories3) AS X CROSS APPLY cat.nodes ('/M') AS splitted(x) 
order by category
```

Also, my actual dataset is not about fruit categories, this is just a simple example of how my data is structured.

---

Edit 2: My main question right now is, how to keep track of the parent rows when inserting the children, like how can I tell that both Oranges and Apples are children of "Fruit".

Comment: Can you share the code of what effort you had made so far?

Comment: For start you would need a splitting function - there are plenty available on the net, look for one.

Comment: Yes I already split the data, updated my question with a runnable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea how to do it, using recursive CTE to sort you parent-child relationships.

I have started by using your query as a source without changing it (CTE_Source). Next two CTEs are some preparing of data.

First CTE - strip down everything right of found category to get correct path and filter just distinct values.

Second CTE - using previously created path now we can assign IDs (with DENSE_RANK function) and calculate level of every row (count number of slashes)

Finally using calculated Path and Level columns now it shouldn't be too hard to go recursively and find each category's ParentID

```
WITH CTE_Source AS 
(
  SELECT distinct X.category,
     splitted.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS cat  
 FROM  (SELECT  category,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(category, '\', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS cat  
     FROM  food_categories3) AS X CROSS APPLY cat.nodes ('/M') AS splitted(x) 
)
, CTE_Prep1 AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
     cat
    , LEFT(category, PATINDEX ('%'+cat+'%', category) + LEN(cat) - 1) AS Path
    FROM CTE_Source s
)
, CTE_Prep2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Path) AS ID
    , * 
    , LEN(Path) - LEN(REPLACE(Path, '\', '')) AS Level
    FROM CTE_Prep1
)
, RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, CAST(NULL AS BIGINT) AS ParentID
    FROM CTE_Prep2
    WHERE Level = 0

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT p.*, r.ID
    FROM CTE_Prep2 p
    INNER JOIN RCTE r ON p.Level = r.Level +1 AND p.Path LIKE r.Path + '%'
)
SELECT * FROM RCTE
ORDER BY ID
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a97f/1)